# Creating Self-signed Certificate Chain with openssl

Tags: openssl, chain, self-signed-certificate, certificate-signing-request

I trying to create a Self-signed certificate chain for simulations, but when I try to import the server's certificate it looks like it's not part of the chain.

Here is what I did:

Creating a Private key:

openssl genrsa -out RootCA.key 4096

Creating a new Certificate and sign it with the previous private key:

openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key RootCA.key -out RootCA.crt

Create a new Private key for Intermediate:

openssl genrsa -out IntermediateCA.key 4096

Create a Certificate Signing Request for the Intermediate's certificate:

openssl req -new -key IntermediateCA.key -out IntermediateCA.csr

Create a certificate from the CSR and sign it with the private key of the Root CA:

openssl x509 -req -days 1000 -in IntermediateCA.csr -CA RootCA.crt -CAkey RootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out IntermediateCA.crt

Add the new Certificate of Root CA to trusted host of your operation system:

cp *.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

Update-ca-certificates

Create a new private key for a server:

openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096

Create a new Certificate Signing Request for the server's certificate:

Note: this common name field on the request must match the FQDN of the server.

openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

Create a certificate from the CSR and sign it with the private key of the Intermediate CA:

openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA IntermediateCA.crt -CAkey IntermediateCA.key -set_serial 0101 -out server.crt -days 500 -sha1

But it looks like isolated certificates:

[Commands-Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NOOl.jpg)

And I would like to simulate this:

[Expected-Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kAFL.jpg)

OpenSSL Print:

```html
% openssl x509 -text -in server.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 101 (0x65)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=IL, O=new, CN=yoyo
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 15 08:49:53 2022 GMT
            Not After : Apr 28 08:49:53 2024 GMT
        Subject: C=IL, O=new, CN=server
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c6:ab:06:38:e9:10:11:64:6f:62:53:07:37:12:
                    66:4f:02:88:6c:b6:a1:b0:57:c0:5b:49:67:f1:b8:
                    78:90:d0:c3:44:bc:d0:94:e7:24:4b:01:41:43:d1:
                    6d:e5:ff:4f:6d:79:52:39:e6:c9:f6:5c:ba:4b:0c:
                    8f:a2:3a:dd:de:d5:a6:13:36:4c:d3:dc:7c:3b:59:
                    19:1d:19:05:8c:18:1b:0c:5d:2d:b2:0c:5a:1c:00:
                    b4:fe:4c:de:55:10:15:81:9e:3c:c9:db:be:ac:a5:
                    a4:cc:a9:8b:79:f9:d6:43:96:aa:35:1e:ad:50:c3:
                    3b:0f:35:af:97:a7:fb:30:8e:ac:fe:8c:9e:45:23:
                    17:9b:e2:19:16:f2:fe:bb:8e:c4:7f:37:ee:99:34:
                    2c:bf:f8:a4:8a:30:c9:bc:80:4a:f5:ce:38:72:be:
                    67:7e:7e:b7:45:93:95:5f:fd:5b:19:86:d0:c4:f4:
                    e5:4b:ed:e9:48:ef:4d:6a:a1:d4:72:ae:69:1d:20:
                    71:2b:5e:30:a5:b0:19:5a:96:0c:ab:49:d3:92:59:
                    46:df:26:ce:94:8c:e9:3d:e2:3d:ac:67:00:ad:e6:
                    6f:dc:06:67:f8:45:8d:13:78:3a:2e:20:b5:80:c4:
                    27:e1:a3:c9:da:1e:ac:23:78:63:02:02:41:7e:d3:
                    75:d2:86:22:b3:dd:e8:85:eb:6f:ec:da:d2:1d:be:
                    a4:a9:36:41:95:0f:08:07:a8:0a:56:4c:d0:60:e1:
                    ff:a5:ce:c7:02:63:6b:96:5c:90:45:79:2b:aa:c0:
                    db:91:6d:92:31:d7:62:25:e9:bf:40:78:a6:14:da:
                    51:67:e2:84:86:b7:7a:f2:d7:7b:11:50:92:1f:3d:
                    57:6c:c7:13:a9:67:d1:66:f1:4a:cd:ec:89:e3:e2:
                    45:ab:26:bf:ad:35:c2:89:14:c4:10:a9:7b:4e:71:
                    f7:e2:53:28:81:8c:32:fd:70:90:77:9e:30:c9:3d:
                    59:08:bb:00:7c:81:3e:48:10:5a:f1:2c:88:6d:97:
                    0e:c0:8e:31:82:c4:85:af:6c:fc:50:1a:70:a1:b2:
                    33:2e:92:b6:93:df:fb:49:b0:11:d6:00:b7:f9:cf:
                    60:61:53:c9:78:a8:5c:45:3c:b5:6c:8c:dc:8c:7e:
                    61:6e:77:65:c2:38:90:7a:69:08:2c:e2:43:88:f8:
                    1e:31:da:4b:dd:d4:e2:b7:34:d5:ba:23:27:f2:9a:
                    00:56:55:93:d3:3c:f6:ee:26:15:82:79:60:08:46:
                    4a:15:88:2e:ce:57:2e:41:7a:51:83:5b:de:a3:28:
                    33:c1:f2:54:c9:05:a7:ea:6a:60:3c:93:ea:9a:eb:
                    3a:0a:5f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         9c:c2:fe:e2:6c:7b:6c:bb:7c:be:01:91:41:4c:67:3c:2b:1f:
         94:8e:05:76:3b:89:f2:4c:7f:e7:b8:93:1e:f1:6c:15:59:f0:
         c9:71:3a:79:9f:c5:59:cc:2d:1a:54:fa:0a:2b:ed:71:db:17:
         bf:4e:9b:d2:a7:ce:a0:58:4a:29:66:b7:88:69:d9:a7:74:75:
         33:43:4c:b1:d4:2f:13:1c:e8:d3:92:df:2c:81:31:52:37:76:
         0b:12:70:6a:e4:9b:4d:6a:80:a6:52:e5:23:54:78:f4:2f:8d:
         34:62:89:41:68:f1:0d:b1:3e:5b:1c:01:3e:26:f4:f5:b3:0e:
         b4:e2:58:ac:70:c9:61:e5:11:a3:45:32:69:73:7f:bc:da:4c:
         be:31:0d:c2:6b:6a:34:83:0e:e8:a9:15:c5:ce:9b:87:2b:2b:
         2b:69:67:54:5f:12:e2:7c:8d:d2:6b:de:20:42:6d:94:82:74:
         15:8c:71:a3:22:03:0c:16:e6:64:9a:08:1d:3d:58:df:2b:91:
         74:d1:12:ec:46:b4:7f:f5:13:4a:ba:50:b7:51:3b:cc:dd:e8:
         36:60:d3:20:41:4a:41:a0:89:22:fc:80:d8:99:e9:67:da:5d:
         f0:e6:f3:26:d2:a3:e6:e8:a9:69:30:df:53:10:b5:4f:0d:94:
         0b:eb:bd:1c:ff:d9:1d:ab:db:92:ae:5a:aa:7a:84:6f:62:b3:
         5f:71:71:cc:ad:6a:bd:af:84:2f:b0:cd:6a:00:6e:4a:06:fa:
         19:04:60:46:34:cb:5f:b8:25:9d:8b:36:ea:e3:09:11:1c:61:
         73:30:5c:fd:7d:b4:e9:ad:d1:ad:63:61:91:fc:49:da:03:9b:
         00:01:91:c2:a3:bc:97:a3:0d:14:bf:a8:5e:36:4e:7c:6f:3d:
         d3:8a:49:23:e7:1e:d1:67:9d:4a:fe:32:53:2e:df:5c:d3:49:
         3e:17:8d:03:9d:0d:08:26:40:9a:da:79:46:c9:84:f9:1b:09:
         3b:44:f7:3f:b8:76:20:4a:15:eb:88:8b:be:00:25:18:3f:e3:
         65:dc:a2:d7:80:81:bd:21:53:da:b2:eb:9f:43:f6:a7:41:1a:
         65:f5:4f:7f:8d:3d:3d:f9:7e:d9:17:15:68:a4:df:03:40:7f:
         ec:bd:77:4f:94:4f:8b:38:2f:1e:80:b8:e9:40:c5:cf:d5:86:
         28:e6:20:42:91:58:94:6d:0c:9e:9e:e6:dd:2f:4c:82:50:70:
         f3:d7:aa:b0:6f:a7:23:16:08:1f:a9:cf:69:32:40:ae:2e:51:
         11:2d:dd:80:9a:df:88:ec:82:b0:f4:04:d9:66:80:99:b5:38:
         87:0e:03:3d:6f:f3:90:b8
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: What OS and what application are you referring to?

Comment: Creating with openssl - just to create the chain certificates. why the OS is matters ? its an Ubuntu and apache service.

Comment: Because different OS use different truststores. Even different applications use different truststores. For example, `wget` does not use the openssl truststore by default, Java uses its own truststore by default, browsers may use their own truststore or the OS truststore. So you may need to add the root certificate to the truststore of your application.

Comment: I want to create the certificate with a chain, no to add it to a trust store of an application or an OS. 
The first step is to create it, after that, I can understand why it's relevant which app, and where to store it.

Comment: I see. However, with what application are you looking at the certificates in the screenhots under _Commands-Results_? If you do not import them in a truststore (but in your question, you do), then how do you check the trust chain? I'm sorry, that's not clear to me. Can you display the certificates you created using `openssl x509 -text -in <certificate.pem>` and add that information to your question, please.

Comment: ok, I have uploaded it. I would like to create a certificate that has a chain (same as any website) I would use this certificate for apache on ubuntu and I would like to see the certificate signed by intermediate ca which signed by a root ca. then I would install the root ca certificate on the client which will browse the site on the apache service from ubuntu server.